# jquery ajax request is not sending cookies from jsp and servlet application to spring cloud api gateway application

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring-boot, spring-cloud-gateway

monolith JSP servlet application saved oauth2 access token and refresh token in a cookie if a user is successfully authenticated as shown in the following code.

[image]

```
if(authenticated) {
                    String accessToken = getUserAccessToken(userStr,passStr);
                    if(!accessToken.isEmpty()) {
                    Cookie cookie = new Cookie("access_token", accessToken);
                    cookie.setPath("/");
                    //cookie.setHttpOnly(true);
                    cookie.setDomain("localhost");
                    //TODO: When in production must do cookie.setSecure(true);
                    cookie.setMaxAge(3600);
                    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
                    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:8081");
                    response.addCookie(cookie);
                    }
                    
                    if(!refreshToken.isEmpty()) {
                        Cookie cookie = new Cookie("refresh_token", refreshToken);
                        cookie.setPath("/");
                        //cookie.setHttpOnly(true);
                        cookie.setDomain("localhost");
                        //TODO: When in production must do cookie.setSecure(true);
                        cookie.setMaxAge(10000);
                        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
                        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:8081");
                        response.addCookie(cookie);
                    }
                }
```

monolith jsp and servlet application send a ajax request to microservice app through the spring cloud gateway as shown in the below code.

```
var token = readCookie('access_token');


$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
                url: "http://localhost:8081/api/v1/users/bulkUpload",
                xhrFields: {
                    withCredentials: true
                },
                data: newData,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                crossDomain: true,
                cache: false,
                timeout: 600000,
                success: function (data) {


........
                    
                    
                    
                },
                error: function (e) {
                   
                },
                beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);
                    xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
                    $('body').addClass("loading");
                }
                
            });
```

monolith jsp and servlet app is runing on port 8080 in jboss server(http://localhost:8080) and apigateway is runing on port 8081 in embedded tomcat server(http://localhost:8081).

in spring cloud gateway i have implemented a filter to capture the cookies and headers sent from monolith app AJAX request as below.

```
@Component
public class AccessTokenCheckingGlobalFilterPre extends AbstractGatewayFilterFactory<AccessTokenCheckingGlobalFilterPre.Config> {

    

    public AccessTokenCheckingGlobalFilterPre() {
        super(AccessTokenCheckingGlobalFilterPre.Config.class);
    }

    @Override
    public GatewayFilter apply(AccessTokenCheckingGlobalFilterPre.Config config) {
        return (exchange, chain) -> {
             Route route = exchange.getAttribute(ServerWebExchangeUtils.GATEWAY_ROUTE_ATTR);
             ServerHttpRequest request = null;
             if (route != null) {
                
                
                 request = exchange.getRequest();
                 ServerHttpResponse response = exchange.getResponse();
                 
                 HttpHeaders headers = request.getHeaders(); **// cookies not contained in headers**
                 List<String> authorizationHeader = headers.get(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION);
                 String value = authorizationHeader.get(0);
                 
                 MultiValueMap<String, HttpCookie> cookies = request.getCookies(); **// cookies null**

                
                 
             }
             
             return chain.filter(exchange.mutate().request(request).build());
            
            
            
        };
    }

    public static class Config {

    }
}
```

but this request object

request = exchange.getRequest();

**doesnt contain any cookies and it is null. cookies are not contained in headers aswell.
why cookies are not sending to apigateway side with ajax request.**